# Strange ifstream to ofstream redirection

Tags: c++

I was reading a project in which I found this line. I am not able to understand what this line does.

```
std::ofstream("img_preview.jpg", std::ios::binary) << std::ifstream("img.jpg", std::ios::binary).rdbuf();
```

I tried to search this kind of syntax but couldn't find proper reference. Please help me out.

Comment: Basically it's copying a file, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt, it's item #9

Comment: That line is doing a lot of things.  Opening an output file stream in binary mode as an anonymous object.  Opening an input file stream in binary mode as an anonymous object.  Output via `<<` the input file's read buffer to the output stream.  Destructing both anonymous objects.  Which part do you not understand?

Comment: I didn't understood the syntax at all. Thanks john and Eljay. :-)